# Interstitial ads (admob) button to open second activity (page 2)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I have some doubts about whether it is correct how the Admob interstitial code is implemented in my application.

The objective is to show interstitial ad when pressing the button that is in MainActivity to open Activity 2.

Example MainActivity (button)

```
public void page1(View view)  
{

    Intent i = new Intent (this, activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);

 
    if (mInterstitialAd != null ) {
        mInterstitialAd.show(this);
    }

}
```

The code works fine, but would it be correct?.

---

Another question related to the show(...):
I have seen these 2 versions

```
mInterstitialAd.show(this);
or
mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
```

which would be the best?

Sorry I just started and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yes, its correct way to implement it. you should start activity and then show interstitial ad so that ad appears on top of that activity. upon closing ad activity2 will be visible for user to interact.

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah can you explain how this is the correct way to show? First `Intent` is calling or `mInterstitialAd`?

Comment: @lina0i0-29 Does your code work fine and `mInterstitialAd` show before going to Activity2?

Comment: If you write show method before startActivity then interstitial with shown on screen and immediately it will hide due to activity starts. which is violation. so to avoid this call show after the startActivity or use onAdClosed callback to avoid hiding ad

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah Thanks for the answer, Another question related to the show(...):
I have seen these 2 versions.
 mInterstitialAd.show(this); 
or
mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this); 
which would be the best?

Comment: this and MainActivity.this both represent the Activity context in this case, so no difference you can use either of them

Comment: @MDev It has worked for me, the InterstitialAd is displayed well

Comment: @Iina0i0-29 check this link for correct ways to implement intr. ads - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-user-launches-app%2Cdisallowed-example-user-exits-app%2Cdisallowed-example-recurring-interstitials%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitials-that-impact-navigation%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-when-opening-app%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-after-page-load%2Crecommendation-how-to-fix-a-violation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Interstitial Ad implementation guide](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-after-page-load%2Crecommendation-how-to-fix-a-violation),

You should not show interstitial ads after the activity has loaded. Interstitial ad should be shown at a natural transition point. You should not show ads after page/activity is loaded. You must first show the ad and start the activity when the ad is dismissed/failed_to_show.

**Disallowed process**

[image]

**Allowed process**

[image]

- Images from the [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-after-page-load%2Crecommendation-how-to-fix-a-violation) to make the process easier to understand

Here's an example:

```
public void openNewActivity()  
{
    // Create the Intent
    Intent i = new Intent (this, activity2.class);

    // Check mInterstitialAd 
    if (mInterstitialAd != null ) {
        // Create callback 
        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                // Don't forget to make mIntersttialAd null
                mInterstitialAd = null;

                // times to start the activity
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                // Don't forget to make mIntersttialAd null
                mInterstitialAd = null;

                // times to start the activity
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
        //  Now show the ad
        mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
    } else {
        // we don't have an interstitial ad to show
        // start the activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**Hope this will help.**

Please note that AdMob has not forwared any code in any of its documents as a sample implementation guide which would be perfect according to its policy. But the code  I've provided above, seems be a bit like the guidance given in the above [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-after-page-load%2Crecommendation-how-to-fix-a-violation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this code works for you? my option is very simple and I think (not sure) that it is correct. (I'm a bit lost xd)

Comment: @lina0i0, In your code, you have called `startActivity(i)` to show `activity2.class` and then you called `mInterstitialAd.show()`. It means ad will be shown just after activity2 is opened. It seems to be against Admob Policy. Check for the link I've provided in post for more deatils. Interstitial ad should be shown at a natural break point. Means user chooses an action > Interstitial is shown > Next page/Activity loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and the answer, another question would not need a - onAdClosed()? I don't see it in the example

Comment: But `com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback` doesn't have such mothod i.e. `onAdClosed()`. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/FullScreenContentCallback) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests I think that the two versions are correct but in the end I will use this code. (`play-services-ads:21.0.0`)

**How do you see it?** Is the implementation correct?

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private static final String TAG = "InfoApp";
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


     //***** Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.*********** -//
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        //**********************************************************//

      adrequest_interstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      InterstitialAd.load(this,ConfigPubli.Ads_interstitial, adrequest_interstitial,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd)
                    {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError)
                    {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }

                });
     }


      public void adstot(Intent i){


        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                mInterstitialAd = null;
                startActivity(i);
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                mInterstitialAd = null;
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });
    }



    public void page2(View view){ //button

        Intent i = new Intent (this, Activity2.class);
        i.putExtra("valor","page2");

        int randomAd = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && randomAd<=1) {   
            adstot(i);
            mInterstitialAd.show(this);   
        }
        else{
            startActivity(i);
        }   
     }
}
```

Thank you for your answers ;-)

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah  how do you see this version?

Comment: @Gouranga Das , In the end I used your example with a touch up, how do you see it? I have added all the example code below. Thanks for your help